# How to make Left join or Inner join in my Scenario using Sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures, left-join

I want to bring all the records from left table and also want to show the records from right table which is matched with left table.

**1.ItemDynamic** [Left table]

```
ItemID    StoreID    SnapShotQuantity
-------------------------------------
111       1201          50
111       1001          25
111       5000          75
111       7777          100
```

**2.Sub Query** my right table is sub query

Here is my sub query

```
SELECT 
    ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode,
    ViewItemMovement.StoreID,
    ViewItemMovement.ItemDescription,
    ViewItemMovement.Brand,
    Sum(ViewItemMovement.Quantity) Quantity,
    ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity SnapShotQuantity,
    ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity - Sum(ViewItemMovement.Quantity) SOH,
    Item.cost,
    (ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity - Sum(ViewItemMovement.Quantity)) * Item.cost AS ExtendedCost

FROM 
    FT_ViewItemMovement ViewItemMovement 
    left join Item with(NoLock) on Item.ItemLookupCode = ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode 
    left join ItemDynamic with(NoLock) on ItemDynamic.ItemID = Item.ID and ItemDynamic.StoreID = ViewItemMovement.StoreID

WHERE brand = 'PEPSI'
Group By  
    ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode,
    ViewItemMovement.StoreID,
    ViewItemMovement.ItemDescription,
    ViewItemMovement.Brand,
    Item.Cost,
    ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity
```

**Sub query result will be like below**

```
ItemID    StoreID    Quantity    SnapShotQuantity   (pls leave other columns)
-------------------------------------------------
111       1201       335            50
111       1001       223            25
```

**3.Item** [This table have ItemLookupCode's ID,called ItemID]

```
ItemLookupCode   ID
------------------------
11121111         111
```

I tried the following query, to bring all records from **ItemDynamic with ItemID and StoreID [Left Table]** and **matched records from sub query [Right table], it shows Quantity,SnapshotQuantity,ExtendedPrice**

```
select 
    id.ItemID,
    id.StoreID,
    ViewItemMovements.ItemLookupCode,
    ViewItemMovements.ItemDescription,
    ViewItemMovements.Brand,
    case when item.ItemLookupCode = item.ItemLookupCode 
        and id.StoreID = ViewItemMovements.StoreID then ViewItemMovements.Quantity 
        else 0 end Quantity,
    id.SnapShotQuantity,
    case when item.ItemLookupCode = item.ItemLookupCode 
        and id.StoreID = ViewItemMovements.StoreID then ViewItemMovements.SOH
        else id.SnapShotQuantity end SOH,

    Item.cost,
    (id.SnapShotQuantity - (case when item.ItemLookupCode = item.ItemLookupCode 
        and id.StoreID = ViewItemMovements.StoreID then ViewItemMovements.Quantity 
        else 0 end))* Item.cost AS ExtendedCost

from 
    ItemDynamic id
    left join Item with(NoLock) on Item.ID = id.ItemID 
    left join (
        SELECT 
            ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode,
            ViewItemMovement.StoreID,
            ViewItemMovement.ItemDescription,
            ViewItemMovement.Brand,
            Sum(ViewItemMovement.Quantity) Quantity,
            ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity SnapShotQuantity,
            ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity - Sum(ViewItemMovement.Quantity) SOH,
            Item.cost,
            (ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity - Sum(ViewItemMovement.Quantity)) * Item.cost AS ExtendedCost

        FROM 
            FT_ViewItemMovement ViewItemMovement 
            left join Item with(NoLock) on Item.ItemLookupCode = ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode 
            left join ItemDynamic with(NoLock) on ItemDynamic.ItemID = Item.ID and ItemDynamic.StoreID = ViewItemMovement.StoreID

        --WHERE brand = 'PEPSI'
        Group By  
            ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode,
            ViewItemMovement.StoreID,
            ViewItemMovement.ItemDescription,
            ViewItemMovement.Brand,
            Item.Cost,
            ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity
) ViewItemMovements     on ViewItemMovements.ItemLookupCode = Item.ItemLookupCode 
    and ViewItemMovements.StoreID = id.StoreID 
    where  ViewItemMovements.Brand = 'pepsi' and id.StoreID <> 1303
    order by ViewItemMovements.ItemLookupCode,StoreID
```

> I am giving more importance to those following columns especially **Quantity and SnapShotQuantity like below**

```
ItemID    StoreID    Quantity    SnapShotQuantity  (pls leave other columns) 
-------------------------------------------------
111       1201       335            50
111       1001       223            25
111       5000        0             75
111       7777        0             100
```

> But I am getting the subquery result only when I run the whole query. What I did mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your `LEFT JOIN` is becoming like an `INNER JOIN` because of your `WHERE` clause.

To quickly illustrate the issue, let's say I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (i INT);
INSERT @A (i) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

DECLARE @B TABLE (i INT);
INSERT @B (i) VALUES (2), (3);

SELECT *
FROM @A AS A
LEFT JOIN @B AS B ON B.i = A.i;
```

I'll get three rows as a result: `(1, null), (2, 2), (3, 3)`.

But let's say I only want to join table B where i = 3. If I alter the query like this:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (i INT);
INSERT @A (i) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

DECLARE @B TABLE (i INT);
INSERT @B (i) VALUES (2), (3);

SELECT *
FROM @A AS A
LEFT JOIN @B AS B ON B.i = A.i
WHERE B.i = 3;
```

I only get one row as a result: `(3, 3)`.

What I should do instead is make the WHERE clause part of the LEFT JOIN like such:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (i INT);
INSERT @A (i) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

DECLARE @B TABLE (i INT);
INSERT @B (i) VALUES (2), (3);

SELECT *
FROM @A AS A
LEFT JOIN @B AS B ON B.i = A.i AND B.i = 3;
```

And my results will look like: `(1, null), (2, null), (3, 3)` *because it's part of the conditions of the LEFT JOIN instead of a WHERE clause at the end*.

The **TL;DR** here is that you should change this part:

`where  ViewItemMovements.Brand = 'pepsi' and id.StoreID <> 1303`

to this:

`AND ViewItemMovements.Brand = 'pepsi' WHERE id.StoreID <> 1303`